# Is it possible to delete "all contacts" related to an Account before inserting a contact with that Account

Tags: before-trigger

Scenario: Before insertion of a Contact which is having LastName and AccountId='XYZ', delete all contacts related to the Account 'XYZ'.
Is this scenario possible to trigger ?

Comment: Yes...but why would you do that?

Comment: providing the code to do this is like someone telling you to type 'format c:' at the command prompt. Of course it can be done but there are so many "what ifs" that putting this in a production org is not advisable. Use data loader to remove records purposely and not via code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I'd do like this:

```
trigger triggerName on Contact (before insert) 
{
  List<Contact> contacts2Delete = new List<Contact>();
  contacts2Delete = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ParentId :='XYZ'];
  delete contacts2Delete;
}
```

In general, dynamically:

```
 trigger triggerName on Contact (before insert) 
 {
  List<Contact> contacts2Delete = new List<Contact>();

  for(Contact contact : Trigger.new)
     if(contact.AccountId!=null) 
         contacts2Delete = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ParentId :=contact.AccountId];

  delete contacts2Delete;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trigger delCon on Contact(before insert){
{

 list< id > idlist = new list< id >();


   for(contact c:Trigger.new)
   {
       if(c.accountid!=null)
       {
             idlist.add(c.accountid);
      }

   }

 if(idlist.size()>0)
 {
   list<contact> conlist=[select accountid from contact where accountid in :idlist];
    if(conlist.size()>0)      
    {
         delete conlist;
    }
 }
}
```